# php mysql - how to arrange array results contain key value

Tags: php, mysql

Iam using the below code to get data from database and its work fine, but my problem is the result containing duplicate value and not arranged as I want.

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"select user_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM mohamiusermeta  where meta_key IN ('websiteurl', 'profile_photo', 'Office', 'address_user', 'agentarea', 'offertext' , 'officename', 'cover_photo', 'membertype') group by user_id");
$newarray = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{

 $subArray=array();

    $output[$row['meta_key']] = $row['meta_value'];

    $subArray['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
        $subArray['Office']=$output['Office']; 

        $subArray['officename']=$output['officename']; 
        $subArray['address_user']=$output['address_user']; 
        $subArray['profile_photo']=$output['profile_photo']; 
        $subArray['cover_photo']=$output['cover_photo']; 
        $subArray['agentarea']=$output['agentarea']; 
            $subArray['offertext']=$output['offertext']; 
            $subArray['websiteurl']=$output['websiteurl']; 
            $subArray['membertype']=$output['membertype']; 

    $newarray[]= array_filter($subArray);


    }

     json_encode($newarray);

     echo(json_encode($newarray,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

     mysqli_close();
```

the result

```
 1
 user_id    "1"
 Office "مؤسسة السنان للعسل الطبيعي ( عمان )"
address_user    "سلطنة عمان - بانوراما مول"
2   
  user_id   "1"
 Office "مؤسسة السنان للعسل الطبيعي ( عمان )"
address_user    "سلطنة عمان - بانوراما مول"
profile_photo   "profile_photo.jpg"
3   
 user_id    "1"
Office  "مؤسسة السنان للعسل الطبيعي ( عمان )"
address_user    "سلطنة عمان - بانوراما مول"
profile_photo   "profile_photo.jpg"
cover_photo "cover_photo.jpg"
```

but I want to get

```
 1
 user_id: "1"
 Office: "officename"
 profile_photo: "profile.jpg
 user_address: "address"
 websiteurl: "url"
 ........

 2
 user_id: "2"
 Office: "officename"
 profile_photo: "profile.jpg
 user_address: "address"
 websiteurl: "url"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: use  `groupBy(user_id)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will get an SQL error with your code. That is because you select the fields `user_id, meta_key, meta_value` but you group your results by `user_id`. **Directly selecting fields that are not grouped is not allowed.** To solve the issue remove the `GROUP BY` clause. You need to group your result programmatically in PHP.

The problem you encounter in your code is, that you fill the `$output` array simultaniously to accessing it in your `while` loop.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $subArray=array();

    $output[$row['meta_key']] = $row['meta_value'];

    $subArray['user_id']=$row['user_id'];

    $subArray['Office']=$output['Office']; 
    ...
    $subArray['membertype']=$output['membertype']; 

    $newarray[]= array_filter($subArray);
}
```

As you can see, you only fill one field of the `$output` array for each row, while you access all of the fields for each row, as well.

What you want to do instead is grouping all the rows you have by their `user_id`. To do this, you can use the `user_id` as a key in your output array and add all the meta data to the inner array referenced by it:

```
$newarray = [];
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row['user_id'], $newarray) {
        // Adds a new inner array for the specific user and initializes it with the user_id
        $newarray[$row['user_id']] = ['user_id' => $row['user_id']];
    }
    if (!empty($row['meta_value']) || is_numeric($row['meta_value'])) {
        // Adds a specific meta value to an inner user array
        $newarray[$row['user_id']][$row['meta_key']] = $row['meta_value'];
    }
}
```

With this code you will get your desired output. By using `empty()` in combination with `is_numeric()` as a condition to add a meta value to the inner array, you get rid of the neccessarity to use `array_filter()`, because no falsy values will be stored. In case your meta values might be booleans as well you should add `|| is_boolean()` to this condition.